# yii problemas con mi menu dependiente

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, base-de-datos, yii

Tengo problemas para hacer un menu dependiente, el problema que tengo es que solo me toma los datos de un menu y el otro toma todos los valores por defecto.

Esta es la funcion de mi controlador:

```
public function actionAjaxResultados(){
        if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest){
            if (isset($_POST['id_establecimiento'])) {

            $idEstablecimiento = $_POST['id_establecimiento'];
            echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => ''), 'Todos');
            $departamentos = Departamento::model()->findAll('id_establecimiento =:establecimiento', array(':establecimiento' => $idEstablecimiento));
            $edificios = Edificio::model()->findAll('id_establecimiento =:establecimiento', array(':establecimiento' => $idEstablecimiento));



            foreach($edificios as $edificio ){

                //$resultado = CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => $departamentos->id), CHtml::encode($departamentos->nombre));  
                $resultado1 = CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => $edificio->id), CHtml::encode($edificio->nombre));
                echo CJSON::encode(array('edificio' => $resultado1));
                //var_dump($resultado);
            }

            foreach($departamentos as $departamento ){

                $resultado2 = CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => $departamento->id), CHtml::encode($departamento->nombre));
                //$resultado = CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => $edificio->id), CHtml::encode($edificio->nombre));
                echo CJSON::encode(array('departamento' => $resultado2));
                //var_dump($resultado);
            }
            /*
                echo CJSON::encode(array(
                  'edificio'=>$resultado1,
                  'departamento'=>$resultado2,
              ));

             */
        }
    }
}
```

Lo comentado son intentos de hacer algo

Este es el admin:

```
 array(
    'name' => 'id_establecimiento',
    'value' => '$data->establecimiento->nombre',
    'filter' => CHtml::activeDropDownList($model, 'id_establecimiento',
        CHtml::listData($establecimiento, 'id', 'nombre'),
        array(
            'empty' => 'Todos',
            /* 'ajax' => array(
                             'type' => 'POST',
                             'url' => CController::createUrl('equipo/ajaxResultados'),
                             'data' => array('id_establecimiento' => 'js:this.value'),
                             'update' => '#Equipo_id_departamento',
             )*/

        'ajax' => array(
            'type' => 'POST',
            'url' => CController::createUrl('equipo/ajaxResultados'),
            'data' => array('id_establecimiento' => 'js:this.value'),
            'update' => '#Equipo_id_edificio',
            'update' => '#Equipo_id_departamento'
            /*'success'=>"function(){ 
                 $('#Requerimiento_id_edificio').html(edificio);
                 $('#Requerimiento_id_departamento').html(departamento);

             }",*/

        )
    )),
```